# Tiny CAD Addon enabling error

Tags: add-on

Downloaded the latest copy of Tiny Cad but it throws out an error
when I try to enable it. See the image below. I have no clue what
is happening. Does anyone have a solution to this?

I am using Blender 2.75.
Tiny Cad's version is 1.2.0

[image]

Comment: same problem as the duplicate. Here you have to rename you folder to `mesh_tinyCAD`